# Flask in docker: different relative import in Dockerfile build and docker-compose

Tags: python, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a simple Flask application with the following structure:

```
|__app     
|  └── __init__.py
|  └── config.py
└── docker-compose.yml
└── Dockerfile
```

Key here is that `__init__.py` imports `config.py`. I use docker-compose to run the application in a container in DEBUG mode, while the end product is a container solely build from the Dockerfile.

The `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask

from .config import config


def create_app(config_name='development'):
    """Create the app."""
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def index():
        return 'hello world' 

    return app
```

The `Dockerfile` builds the application in a docker container:

```
FROM python:3.6-alpine
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn
COPY app/ /app
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8000
CMD gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0:8000 "__init__:create_app()"
```

The `docker-compose.yml` is used for development: it shares the app directory so it enables the app to run in DEBUG mode:

```
version: '3'
services:
  svc1:
    build: .
    entrypoint:
      - flask
      - run
      - --host=0.0.0.0
    environment:
      FLASK_DEBUG: 1
      FLASK_APP: __init__.py
    ports: ['5000:5000']
    volumes: ['./app:/app']
```

In the main folder you can run the application in debug mode with `docker-compose up --build -d` and you navigate to localhost:5000  it returns "hello world".

But if you build the image with `docker build -t exampleapi .` and run the image it complains:

> File "/app/**init**.py", line 3, in module
>
> from .config import config
>
> ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: @Rishav; I understand where it comes from; but I don't understand why since both run the main `__init__.py` from the same directory

Comment: Can you try changing the Gunicorn command to `app.__init__.make_app()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16985066/4759361), to make the relative import work, one of the easier options is to specify the fully dotted name of the module to Gunicorn, like so:

```
app.__init__.create_app()
```

Other options to get this working include:

- Changing your relative import to a form like `from mymodule import as_int`. This will only work if your module name is unique. Otherwise, you can:
- `from mypackage.mymodule import as_int`